# mysqli_connect From Included File Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this mysqli_connect on a file named config.php :

```
$DbServer = 'localhost';
$DbUser = 'username';
$DbPassword = 'password';
$DbName = 'dbname';
$con = mysqli_connect($DbServer, $DbUser, $DbPassword, $DbName);
```

then I have another PHP file named sendingrequest.php :

```
<?php    
session_start();
require_once ('config.php');
$Key = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, $_GET["key"]);
... 
?>
```

this sendingrequest.php always produce this error message :

```
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/public_html/sendingrequest.php on line 4
```

I tried to modify the script by putting mysqli_connect() on the same file, not by require_once() anymore and surprisingly it works...

```
<?php    
session_start();
//require_once ('config.php');

$DbServer = 'localhost';
$DbUser = 'username';
$DbPassword = 'password';
$DbName = 'dbname';
$con = mysqli_connect($DbServer, $DbUser, $DbPassword, $DbName);

$Key = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, $_GET["key"]);
... 
?>
```

what's wrong with my require_once? why mysqli_real_escape_string failed to using it? thanks!

Comment: The only reason I can see is that `require_once 'config.php';` failed. Just try this simple example: `<?php ini_set('display_errors', 1); require_once 'config.php'; ?>`  does it work?